# Node `--inspect` flag with Coffeescript

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

Node has been supporting the [`--inspect` debug flag](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_inspect_host_port) which activates the Google DevTools for the given process. Is there a way to get that flag to work with Coffeescript through the `coffee` command? I tried using the `--nodejs` argument but it doesn't give me a debug link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by calling `node` with the `--inspect` flag and passing the path to the `coffee` executable as the next argument.

eg. `node --inspect-brk $(which coffee) ./test.coffee`